# Flood Fill Algorithm that counts rooms

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, multidimensional-array, flood-fill

I am trying to make a flood fill algorithm that counts the number of empty spaces enclosed by walls.
I am using a 2D String array and the walls are represented by "1" and the empty spaces are null.
Ideally the algorithm should check every String in the array, returning at any point where the String at position map[x][y] isn't null, and count the number of empty spaces enclosed by walls.
However at the minute I am getting an extremely long number for the number of rooms and not sure where I am going wrong.

```
public static void floodFill(int x, int y, String oldChar,  String newChar){

     x = 0;
     y=0;



    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > map.length || y > map[0].length ){
        return;
    }

     if (map[x][y] != oldChar){
         return;
     }

     map[x][y] = newChar;



     // Recursive calls


         floodFill(x - 1, y, oldChar, newChar);

         floodFill(x +1, y, oldChar, newChar);

         floodFill( x, y-1, oldChar, newChar);

         floodFill(x, y+1, oldChar, newChar);


     }

public static void getNumOfRooms(String map[][]){

     roomCount = -1;

     for(x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
         for (y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++){
             if (map[x][y] == null){
                 floodFill(x, y, null, "x");

                 roomCount+=1;
                 System.out.println(map);
             }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you setting x and y to 0 at the top of floodFill()?

Comment: Shouldn't the floodFill parameters be (x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)? You have some questionable coord pairings. Also shouldn't roomCount start at 0?

Comment: I would get an Array out of bounds error if I didn't set the x and y to 0. Essentially I want it to search the whole array starting from [0,0]. Yes the pairings are corrected. roomCount is at -1 because it should count the outside area as 1 space also

Comment: Removing `x = 0; y = 0;` will fix the code. For each empty square you find, you want to flood that room with "x" and count 1 room. Instead, you're flood filling the same room each time (and the second and subsequent flood fills do nothing because `map[0][0]` will already be set to "x").

Comment: Also you may need `>=` rather than `>` in the bounds checks. And perhaps you need to debug your program when it's not working instead of making random changes in the hope that it'll fix the code...

Comment: removing x = 0; y = 0; causes an array index out of bounds error by 50 at the line `if (map[x][y] == null)` . Yeah I admit by debugging skills are practically non-existent, but I am fairly green so excuse me

Comment: As a small optimization you may get `map[x]` only once in the first loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too lazy to try your code but here some things (some are already mentioned in the comments):

1. **you are missing inside `map[][]` checks for recursive calls**

   Yes you got this:

   ```
   if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > map.length || y > map[0].length ) return;
   ```

   But that is not good (even useless) because your recursive calls then can access up to `+2` and `-1` index out of bounds. Also should be `>= map[0].length`. I would remove that if completely and instead use:

   ```
   if (x>              0) floodFill(x-1,y, oldChar, newChar);
   if (x<map   .length-1) floodFill(x+1,y, oldChar, newChar);
   if (y>0)               floodFill(x,y-1, oldChar, newChar);
   if (y<map[0].length-1) floodFill(x,y+1, oldChar, newChar);
   ```
2. **What array are you flood filling?**

   **I am no JAVA coder so I may be wrong in this** but if I use **C++** analogy then:

   ```
   public static void getNumOfRooms(String map[][])
   ```

   will create new local copy of `map[][]` so you are accessing the local copy inside (unless it means pointer not array copy). So you are possibly checking values in the local copy but your flood fill is accessing the original map instead:

   ```
   public static void floodFill(int x, int y, String oldChar,  String newChar)
   ```

   So no change in local `map[][]` will cause you are counting number of spaces not rooms. I would remove the `String map[][]` operand from `getNumOfRooms` header to remedy that.
3. **You are forgetting the background**

   Most room layouts have outer border space that does not belong to any room. So you should scan the outer most rectangle in your map and if any space found fill it with either wall character or some temporary character prior to your counting rooms to avoid counting it as room. You are setting the counter to `-1` instead which is incorrect (what if there is no outer space) it should be `0`.
4. **using `null` character**

   In some cases using `null` character in string can be dangerous as some string operations use it as string terminator. Not sure if it is also the case for your **JAVA** `string` but if yes for example in first map line is usually the outer space so the line may start with `null` which can change the `map[0].length` to zero for some operations destroying the layout of your map. I would use ASCII space  instead it is much safer and also it is far easier to print out the `map` then.

Comment: Thank you so much! After some tweaking along your guidelines, it successfully prints the total number of rooms in the array. Eternally Grateful